# How to use png files as icons in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, svg, icons, png

To be able to use my icons, I upload them to [fluttericon.com](https://fluttericon.com) but it only accepts svg files. Since my icons are in .png format, I'm using a converter to convert them into svg. After the conversion, I upload them but it seems like they are not identified correctly by fluttericon.com, yet I'm unable to see icons on the app.

There is a custom bottom navigation bar in my app and it only accepts iconData as argument. So I have to use an actual icon. I tried using the custom icon on AppBar to be able know if it's bottom navigation bar causing the problem but it's same.

I read some comments saying the content of svg matters. Cause when I download a random icon in svg format directly and upload it, it's identified properly on [fluttericon.com](https://fluttericon.com). What do I need to do?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?

Comment: Even I am able to use only an IconData. Not any other widget. I cant find the answer to this.

Answer (score 13):

Use `icon: Image.asset("assets/home.png")`

full code example:

```
class MyTabBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyTabBarState createState() => _MyTabBarState();
}

class _MyTabBarState extends State<MyTabBar>  with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int tabIndex=0;



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: tabIndex ==0 ?BottomTabBarHome() 
        :tabIndex == 1? BottomTabBarMail(): BottomTabBarProfile()
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items:  <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Image.asset("assets/home.png", color: Colors.grey,),
            activeIcon: Image.asset("assets/home.png", color: Colors.blue,),
            title: Text('')
          ),
           BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Image.asset("assets/mail.png", color: Colors.grey,),
            activeIcon: Image.asset("assets/mail.png", color: Colors.blue,),
            title: Text('')
          ),
           BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Image.asset("assets/account.png", color: Colors.grey,),
            activeIcon: Image.asset("assets/account.png", color: Colors.blue,),
            title: Text('')
          )
        ],
        currentIndex: tabIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        onTap: (int index){
          setState(() {
            tabIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}

class BottomTabBarHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(" Home Screen"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class BottomTabBarMail extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Mail Screen"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class BottomTabBarProfile extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(" Profile Screen"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using a custom Bottom Navigation Bar which is [this](https://pub.dev/packages/circular_bottom_navigation). It only accepts iconData, not Icon or any other widget. That forces me to use an actual Icon. Then other problems I mentioned begins to occur.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I used my png images as icons:

```
icon: const ImageIcon(
          AssetImage('assets/image.png'),
        ),
```

It worked perfectly for me :).

Comment: Doesn't it increase app size if we use .png image instead of Icon?Or it doesn't affect app size as it treats the image as icon?

Answer (score 2):

pulled some code from my old project:

basic idea is that the `icon` or `activeIcon` named parameter asks for a Widget, includes but not limited to an `Icon` widget.

```
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              title: Text('REALTIME SCHEDULE'),
              activeIcon: TrackIcon(colorValue: Colors.white70),
              icon: TrackIcon(colorValue: Color(0xff424150)),
            ),
```

```
class TrackIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color colorValue;
  TrackIcon({@required this.colorValue});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 33,
      width: 99,
      child: Image.asset(
        'images/track_icon.png',
        height: 25,
        color: colorValue,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In my case, I'm limitied to use IconData on TabItem's of bottom navigation bar I'm using. [This](https://pub.dev/packages/circular_bottom_navigation) is the link to package.

Answer (score 1):

As the above answers are useful (with just a few lines of edit), let me simplify

Use this line of code for using you PNG icons

```dart
icon: Image.asset("assets/home.png", color: Colors.grey,)
```

Now go to the folder containing the files of your flutter package for bottomNavigationBar and either edit the package itself OR copy the files into a folder `flutterApp/packages/your_package/[those dart files]` (second option is better to test with hot reload).

Note: `flutterApp` is the root folder of your flutter app.

Note: If you decided to edit the package itself in `flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/...` then you have to stop and re-run the debugging session after each edit for it to take effect.

Note: If you decided to copy the package files in your `flutterApp` then add them in your pubspecs.yaml as

```dart
dependencies:
  your_package:
    path: packages/your_package
```

Now, what to edit?

Find the constructor parameter `icon` or whatever it is. Now change its type from `IconData` (mostly) to `Widget` and now find the usage with simple searching/looking for the keyword and adjust/fit in the changed icon parameter as a `Widget`.

for example, if the usage looks something like this:

```dart
Icon(
  widget.icon,
  ...
),
```

change it to:

```dart
widget.icon
```

because Icon() is also a widget which used the earlier IconData `widget.icon` and as we have converted that to Widget itself we can simply use `widget.icon` instead of Icon().

Comment: Can you explain more on the widget.icon part?

Answer (score 0):

To add png to our code

1. add the below lines on `pubspec.yaml`

```
  assets:
   - lib/images/swap.png
```

2. in `main.dart` use the same directory

```
  child: Image.asset('lib/images/swap.png')
```